# when i call a function in a controller, it show me 2 time the controller which stop my task

Tags: codeigniter

Hello every body I have a problem when i call to a certain function in controller to update a record, it duplicate the my controller in URL which not let me work fine.Help please thanks in advance..

it show URL like this:
localhost/codetest/practice_controller/practice_controller/practice_update/1

In above  practice_controller is coming two time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities.. either you have a redirect code in your controller which is redirecting in a false way or in the form action you have not written complete URL starting with base_url().

I would suggest to write complete url in form action like

```
<?php echo base_url()?>practice_controller/practice_update/<?php echo $update_id?>
```

Comment: Another option is that he's not using relative URLS I guess, something along the lines of `<a href="controllername/methodname>`

Comment: exactly... that would be the only problem.

Comment: please do not mix `base_url` with `site_url` they are different, and in links such as this it is wise to use `site_url`

Comment: tnxxxxxxxxxx #Dirgh it work fine for me...
#Patrick, #TomXsans..tnx to